# Moto G GPS is inaccurate

Tags: gps, motorola-moto-g, gps-tracking

I am running CyanogenMod (12.1) on my Moto G (first generation) and while using mobile data, the GPS is extremely inaccurate when driving. I use Google Maps driving mode which used to be great when I had an iPhone, but using Moto G, Google Maps always display wrong position.

I even had the GPS mode on High Accuracy but did not change much. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it is a [known issue](https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Known_Issues_page_for_falcon) with CM 12.1. 
to fix :

```
fastboot erase modemst1 
fastboot erase modemst2
```